# RDP Client on Vista Home Basic

Tags: rdp

Can I install and run RDP Client on vista home basic?

Answer (score 1):

[From here](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5208-6230-0.html?forumID=102&threadID=236601&messageID=2329834)

*Vista Home does have the remote desktop built in to allow you to remote to other windows systems but you will not be able to remote to it nor join it to a domain.*

So I think you will need to upgrade your Vista version.

**Edit:**

This is for server side rdp.

Comment: You only need to upgrade if you want to run RDP server.  RDP client doesn't need an upgrade.

Comment: Ah good to know that about the client. This will confirm about the server side of things.

Answer (score 1):

[Remote Desktop Connection: frequently asked questions](http://windowshelp.microsoft.com/Windows/en-US/Help/f55326fa-e629-423b-abba-b30f76cc61e61033.mspx) (says it applies to all versions of Vista)

According to 'How do I install Remote Desktop Connection?' the client is already installed.

"Open Remote Desktop Connection by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, clicking All Programs, clicking Accessories, and then clicking Remote Desktop Connection."

Comment: On basic? I don see it. This install came directly from Dell.

Comment: Then as mentioned in another answer, try this: Go to Run (Windows Key + R), type 'mstsc' and hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find the shortcut, go to Run and type MSTSC, press enter. It should open then.